# Entrysubtype: how to avoid printing it?

Tags: biblatex

I am using Overleaf and have some issues with a selective library for my CV. I want to not display all `@articles` from my `.bib` file as some are work in progress and some are published. Therefore, I have different `entrysubtypes`, such as `{myarticle}`, `{workinprogress}`, or `{inrevision}`. My code:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@inbook{OwnPub001,
    author = {Fnu1 Snu1 and Fnu2 Snu2},
    title = {Exampletitel 1},
    year = {2022},
    booktitle = {Booktitle 1},
    editor = {FnuEd1 SnuEd1},
    publisher = {Springer},
    address = {},
    edition = {},
    pages = {},
    doi = {},
    entrysubtype = {section}
}

@article{OwnPub002,
    author = {Fnu1 Snu1 and Fnu3 Snu3},
    year = {2019},
    title = {Exampletitle 2},
    journal = {TestJournal},
    volume = {5},
    number = {},
    pages = {600-623},
    ISSN = {},
    doi = {10.XXXX},
    entrysubtype = {article}
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}

\DeclareLabeldate[article]{\field{year}}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat{apacase}{#1}

\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{entrysubtype}}

\begin{document}
\section{Publications \& Presentations}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,title=Peer-Reviewed Journals,subtype=article]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,title=Book Chapters,subtype=section]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,title=Conferences \& Workshop Items,subtype=conference]
\end{document}
```

When doing that, the apa output always displays the `entrysubtitle` in [] (e.g., `Author, D. 2022. Title [myarticle]. *Journal*`)

I don't want to have the `[entrysubtype]` in my printed references, as it serves only as a sorting argument. Does anyone know how to 'drop' printing the `entrysubtype` in the bibliography?

Comment: Try `\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{entrysubtype}}` and/or `\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{entrysubtype}}`

Comment: didn't work :-(

Comment: or do you suggest another field for typology?

Comment: Could you extend your code fragment into something that can compile please? Include an example `.bib` entry or use the example bib with `biblatex`, we can't test solutions without having a document that we can compile on our computers ourselves. It should begin with your `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` please :)

Comment: added above as here too little characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using my commented solution worked, `\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{entrysubtype}}`. Without `\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{entrysubtype}}`:

[image]

With `\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{entrysubtype}}`:

[image]

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@inbook{OwnPub001,
    author = {Fnu1 Snu1 and Fnu2 Snu2},
    title = {Exampletitel 1},
    year = {2022},
    booktitle = {Booktitle 1},
    editor = {FnuEd1 SnuEd1},
    publisher = {Springer},
    address = {},
    edition = {},
    pages = {},
    doi = {},
    entrysubtype = {section}
}

@article{OwnPub002,
    author = {Fnu1 Snu1 and Fnu3 Snu3},
    year = {2019},
    title = {Exampletitle 2},
    journal = {TestJournal},
    volume = {5},
    number = {},
    pages = {600-623},
    ISSN = {},
    doi = {10.XXXX},
    entrysubtype = {article}
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}

\DeclareLabeldate[article]{\field{year}}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat{apacase}{#1}

\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{entrysubtype}}

\begin{document}
\section{Publications \& Presentations}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,title=Peer-Reviewed Journals,subtype=article]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,title=Book Chapters,subtype=section]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,title=Conferences \& Workshop Items,subtype=conference]
\end{document}
```

That worked on TeXlive 2023 Windows 10 and also on Overleaf 2022 `pdflatex`:

[image]

I am not sure if you tried my comments advice, if you didn't then please bear in mind that lots of questions are solved in the comments for the future, hope this helps!

Comment: now it worked - thank you very much JamesT!